# LXML etree add existing (parsed) Element as SubElement to another (parsed) Element

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml, elementtree

I have two XML structures, `xml_1` and `xml_2`

`xml_1` is a structure that I have created as such:

`xml_1 = etree.Element('xml_1_root')`

`xml_2` is a structure that I've parsed from existing XML data as such:

`xml_2 = etree.parse(xml_2.xml).getroot()`

I'd like to do something like this:

```
for node in xml_2.findall("node"):
    etree.SubElement(xml_1, node)
```

Such that all the structure from the `node` is added as a child to the newly-created `xml_1` structure.

The issue, is that the `SubElement` method (obviously) doesn't work here, as it's unintended use.

My question is: Does the lxml.etree library have a method to add existing (parsed) Elements as SubElements such that any attributes, text, and child node information is preserved?

The issue is that many of the nodes in `xml_2` have children (many of which *also* have children) and I'd rather avoid having to recurse into them to extract all the information granularly.

**Note**: This is not a question of how to *create* an etree SubElement from scratch. It's a question of how to add an existing Element to another tree while preserving the existing data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I should have read the docs a bit more thoroughly.

The etree library [provides the following method](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.append) for a `Element`:

> append(subelement)
>       Adds the element subelement to the end of this element’s internal list of subelements. 
>       Raises TypeError if subelement is not an Element.

So, to add an existing `xml_2_node` into the new `xml_1` structure:

`xml_1.append(xml_2_node)`